# How to configure apache VHost to work with axios.post?

Tags: apache, axios, cors, wamp, vhosts

I'm attempting to call a webservice via *POST* from a create-react-app application to a local vhost running on XAMPP (also tried WAMP) with Windows 10 as the OS.

---

### The local environments

- `http://test.local/` - Local server running on an XAMPP vhost.
- `http://localhost:3000` - create react app url

---

### What calls work in each circumstance

- `axios.get` **responds correctly** and `axios.post` **responds correctly** when made from `test.local/`.
- `axios.get` **responds correctly** and `axios.post` **does not respond**. when made from from `localhost:3000`

---

### The code used in my tests

`axios.post` request that is failing from `localhost:3000`

```
axios.post('http://test.local/load/notifications/', { someData: 'someVal'},
  { headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }).then((resp) => {
     console.log(resp.data); // no response in network tab of developer tools
}, (error) => {
 // The request was made but no response was received
})
```

> I've tried this request *with* and *without* the CORS setting in the configuration object.

---

PHP test file at `test.local/load/notifications/index.php`

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$mockDataFile  = "./mockData.json";
$unencoded = json_decode(file_get_contents($mockDataFile));
echo json_encode($unencoded);
?>
```

> My CORS header on the php page is set to
>   `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`, so I'm assuming it's not
>   CORS related unless my syntax is off.  There is no error message, the
>   endpoint just doesn't return a response.

---

Directory flag in `httpd.conf`

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1.5
</Directory>
```

---

vhost configuration in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:\test\public"
    <Directory  "F:\test\public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ServerName test.local
    ServerAlias test.local
    CustomLog "logs/test.local-access.log" common
    ErrorLog "logs/test.local-error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: My original question was misleading as to the cause.  I'm going to leave the original question as-is in case someone else discovers the problem in the same way as I spent hours googling the issue with no results.  It's an obscure problem that ruined my day, so hopefully this will save someone some pain.

Comment: Please leave a comment if you choose to downvote so I can improve my entries

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After further investigation, **it was a CORS issue caused by the payload in the post request**.  I found that if I made a post request with no data, it worked just like the POST request.  This was fixed by changing my PHP file to the following:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
$mockDataFile  = "./mockData.json";
$unencoded = json_decode(file_get_contents($mockDataFile));
echo json_encode($unencoded);
?>
```

**The missing piece** was `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');`.

---

### This is why the problem was hard to identify in my create-react-app

> This didn't appear to be a CORS issue because there *was no error message* when making the request from the dev server.  I simply didn't think to remove the payload, it was only by accident that I left it out and the request worked.
>
> When making the request from another vhost, I saw the error `Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

---

This new error message led me to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) on setting Access-Control-Allow-Headers .  I recommend reading the article before setting this flag because `*` **allows for anything**, which you may not want.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `<Directory />` on purpose? I'm not sure if that's a typo in your post or if that could be something that's throwing off your config because of the `/` in the opening tag of the Directory node.

I've never seen that in a valid conf (though maybe it's valid?), but it immediately caught my eye almost as though it were a self-closing HTML tag.

Comment: I believe that trailing slash is the folder in this case, it just looks like a self closing tag.  I switched to XAMPP, going to do some testing today soon and see if the issue is fixed.  I'm not really an authority on apache, but in the examples I've seen there's something like <Directory /www> in the opening tag for specific directory configurations and I believe this one is just the catch all

Comment: Modified my answer to show the subsequent directory listing and syntax.  Hopefully that will clear up any confusion.